# python chain a list from a tsv file

Tags: python, line, chain, csv

i have this tsv file containing some paths of links each link is seperated by a ';' i want to use:

In the example below we can se that the text in the file is seperated 
and i only want to read through the last column wich is a path starting with '14th'

```
6a3701d319fc3754    1297740409  166    14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade    NULL
3824310e536af032    1344753412  88     14th_century;Europe;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade  3
415612e93584d30e    1349298640  138    14th_century;Niger;Nigeria;British_Empire;Slavery;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade
```

I want to somehow split the path into a chain  like this:

```
['14th_century', 'Niger', 'Nigeria'....]
```

how do i read the file and remove the first 3 columns so i only got the last one ?

**UPDATE:**

i have tried this now:

```
import re
with open('test.tsv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines[22:len(lines)]:
    re.sub(r"^\s+", " ", line, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    e_line = line.split(' ')
    real_line = e_line[0]
    print real_line.split(';')
```

But the problem is that it not deleting the first 3 columns ?

Answer (score 2):

If the separator betweeen first is only a space and not a serie of spaces or a tab, you could do that

```
with open('file_name') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    e_line = line.split(' ')
    real_line = e_line[3]
    print real_line.split(';')
```

Comment: Its giving me a list index out of range. i tried with 0 in the real_line it did the work but it did not remove the first 3 tab seperated columns ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your updated question.

> But the problem is that it not deleting the first 3 columns ?

There are several mistakes.

Your code:

```
import re
with open('test.tsv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines[22:len(lines)]:
    re.sub(r"^\s+", " ", line, flags = re.MULTILINE)
    e_line = line.split(' ')
    real_line = e_line[0]
    print real_line.split(';')
```

This line does nothing...

```
re.sub(r"^\s+", " ", line, flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

Because `re.sub` function doesn't change your `line` variable, but **returns** replaced string.
So you may want to do as below.

```
line = re.sub(r"^\s+", " ", line, flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

And your regexp `^s\+` matches only string which starts with whitespaces or tabs. Because you use `^`.
But I think you just want to replace consective whitespaces or tabs with one space.
So then, above code will be as below.(Just remove `^` in the regexp)

```
line = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", line, flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

Now, each string in line are separated just one space. So `line.split(' ')` will work as you want.

Next, `e_line[0]` returns first element of `e_line` which is 1st column of the line.
But you want to skip first 3 columns and get 4th column. You can do like this:

```
e_line = line.split(' ')
real_line = e_line[3]
```

OK. Now entire code is look like this.

```
for line in lines:#<---I also changed here because there is no need to skip first 22 lines in your example.
    line = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", line)
    e_line = line.split(' ')
    real_line = e_line[3]
    print real_line
```

output:

```
14th_century;15th_century;16th_century;Pacific_Ocean;Atlantic_Ocean;Accra;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade
14th_century;Europe;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade
14th_century;Niger;Nigeria;British_Empire;Slavery;Africa;Atlantic_slave_trade;African_slave_trade
```

**P.S:**

This line can become more pythonic.

before:

```
for line in lines[22:len(lines)]:
```

after:

```
for line in lines[22:]:
```

And, you don't need to use `flags = re.MULTILINE`, because `line` is single-line in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex for this. The [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) can handle tab-separated files too:

```
import csv

filereader = csv.reader(open('test.tsv', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
path_list = [row[3].split(';') for row in filereader]

print(path_list)
```